# how to access to a value in JSON array containing objects

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, time

I want to loop through my JSON result and get each object's value to sum them.
Here is my JSON result :

```
[{"Duree":"01:00:00"},{"Duree":"00:30:00"},{"Duree":"01:00:00"}]
```

Then i do this in my Ajax method :

```
var xhr1 = getXhr();
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr1.readyState == 4 && xhr1.status == 200){
            Selection = xhr.responseText;
            for(var i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    start = tot;
                }
                else if (i === 0){
                    start = Selection[0];
                }
                if ((i + 1) >= Selection.length) {
                    end = Selection[i + 1];
                    tot = addTimes(start, end);
                }
            }
            alert(tot);
        }
    };
```

My php code which generate my json input :

```
foreach($rep as $Intervention) {
    if ($Intervention['Vacation'] == $idVacation) {
        $Query = 'SELECT Duree FROM fairegammeoperatoire WHERE IDIntervention=:id';
        $rep = $bdd->prepare($Query);
        $custom = $Intervention['IDIntervention'];
        $rep->bindParam(':id',$custom);
        $rep->execute();
        $Duree = $rep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $tot = $Duree;
        array_push($total, $tot);
    }
}
echo json_encode($total);
```

EDIT : Problem was the name of variable xhr used in JSON.parse that wasn't the good one. Has to be xhr1 and not xhr. TY ALL =D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parse it as json object:
It has to be parsed, since the response will be read as string.

```
var xhr1 = getXhr();
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr1.readyState == 4 && xhr1.status == 200){
            Selection = JSON.parse(xhr1.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    start = tot;
                }
                else if (i === 0){
                    start = Selection[0].Duree;
                }
                if ((i + 1) >= Selection.length) {
                    end = Selection[i + 1].Duree;
                    tot = addTimes(start, end);
                }
            }
            alert(tot);
        }
    };
```

Your json must be something like

```
<?php 
$dataArray = array(array("Duree"=>"01:00:00"),array("Duree"=>"02:00:00"),array("Duree"=>"03:00:00"),array("Duree"=>"04:00:00"));
echo json_encode($dataArray);
?>
```

Comment: I tried but someone says to me : if you already json_encode in server side you d'ont have to JSON.parse on client side. That'(s why i had the error "unexpected end in JSON"

Comment: No way man, the Ajax will read the response as string, therefore, you will not be able to access it as josn unless you parse the string to be json again.

Comment: As a normal object so I do Selection.i or Selection[i].Duree ? or Selection->Duree ?

Comment: Selection[i].Duree

Comment: unresolved variable Duree, and again i have "Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse(). For me the json syntax showed in preview section of my php file is OK... an array of object is a godd syntax for json

Comment: I already used that trick but my json input was containing only one object so i acceed it by use Selection.ObjectName.

Comment: Post to me only the json reply. it should be valid json, don't post it from chrome

Comment: I modified my php code to get only objects :    {Duree0: {Duree: "01:00:00"}, Duree1: {Duree: "00:30:00"}, Duree2: {Duree: "01:00:00"},…}
Duree0:{Duree: "01:00:00"}
Duree1:{Duree: "00:30:00"}
Duree2:{Duree: "01:00:00"}

Comment: it is no longer valid json, you need to have it as valid json

Comment: What is the right syntax ? array of objects ? with key and values each time

Comment: Ok i will try this, ty

Comment: I can't build array("Duree":"value") but only array( {Duree : "value"} ) :s

Comment: I get this on Mozilla : [{"Duree":"01:00:00"},{"Duree":"00:30:00"}]  and can't do forEach xhrResponseText :(

Comment: it is true you will get it like that, are you still unable to access it?

Comment: Selection.length undefined, unresolved variable Duree in Selection[i].Duree :\           When i try to console.log(Selection) it returns me Selection.length (32 items)

Comment: can you post the php code that generates this json?